# python pandas re-associate non-numerical data after sum

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

So we have some set of data like this:

```
email, name, price, quantity
a@a.com, alan, 5.3, 2
b@a.com, barbara, 3.99, 1
b@a.com, barbara, 1, 1

...

z@z.com, zed, 3, 1
```

So now if we have this in a dataframe it's pretty easy to do

```
df.groupby(['email']).sum()

          price     quantity
email

a@a.com    5.3      2
b@a.com   4.99      2
```

So no we have the numerical interesting part but not the text part. How can I merge the text parts back in with the sums?

So the desired final state of this would be something like:

```
email, name, price_sum, quantity_sum
a@a.com, alan, 5.3, 2
b@b.com, barbara, 4.99, 2
...
z@z.com, zed, 3, 1
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the desired output. How do you want the "text part" to appear in the data frame?

Comment: Why not just `df.groupby(['name', 'email'], as_index=False).sum()`?

Comment: ah, yes this is a simplified example, we actually have several strings associated with this, like addresses and so on. We're also "trusting" people to always get their email consistently the same, but other data might be inconsistent: "west third street" vs "w 3rd st" in an address for example

Comment: @MrHasquestions got it. In that case, decide on an aggregation function for string values (e.g. `',',join`), and then follow the method in the answers.

Comment: Nope, you're right. Pandas is smarter than I. EDIT: or rather, each approach has its merits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could aggregate, names by taking the first value.

```
In [283]: df.groupby('email').agg({'price': sum, 'quantity': sum, 'name': 'first'
     ...: })
Out[283]:
         price     name  quantity
email
a@a.com   5.30     alan         2
b@a.com   4.99  barbara         2
```

Or, you could aggregate names into a dict.

```
In [281]: df.groupby('email').agg({'price': sum, 'quantity': sum, 'name': lambda x
     ...: : x.value_counts().to_dict()})
Out[281]:
         price             name  quantity
email
a@a.com   5.30     {u'alan': 1}         2
b@a.com   4.99  {u'barbara': 2}         2
```

Or, if you were looking to add as string.

```
In [282]: df.groupby('email').agg({'price': sum, 'quantity': sum, 'name': sum })
Out[282]:
         price            name  quantity
email
a@a.com   5.30            alan         2
b@a.com   4.99  barbarabarbara         2
```

But, for a specific case where your email-name combination is same, you can go with Igor Raush's suggestion `df.groupby(['name', 'email'], as_index=False).sum()`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [DataFrameGroupBy.agg()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) method.

Demo:

```
In [29]: df
Out[29]:
   group    email     name  price  quantity
0      1  a@a.com     alan   5.30         2
1      2  b@a.com  barbara   3.99         1
2      2  b@a.com  barbara   1.00         1
3      1  c@x.com      joe   1.10         2

In [30]: funcs = {'email':', '.join, 'price':'sum', 'quantity':'mean'}

In [31]: df.groupby('group').agg(funcs)
Out[31]:
       price             email  quantity
group
1       6.40  a@a.com, c@x.com         2
2       4.99  b@a.com, b@a.com         1
```

or as [@IgorRaush proposed in the comment using `as_index=False`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860175/python-pandas-re-associate-non-numerical-data-after-sum/41860280#comment70904395_41860175):

```
In [32]: df.groupby('group', as_index=False).agg(funcs)
Out[32]:
   group  price             email  quantity
0      1   6.40  a@a.com, c@x.com         2
1      2   4.99  b@a.com, b@a.com         1
```

Comment: Slightly simpler: `{'email': ','.join}` avoids the `lambda`.

Comment: @IgorRaush, good point, thank you! I've corrected it in the answer

Comment: This is interesting stuff. Pandas is so flexible,